# How To Solve "Too many levels of symbolic links" Problem

Tags: linux-mint, symlink

I need to upgrade Gradle in my Linux Mint box. After installing the latest version, I changed the symbolic link with a command something like

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gradle /alternatives/bin/gradle
ln -s /alternatives/bin/gradle /usr/lib/gradle/6.1/bin
```

That change didn't alter the link at all. Then, I remember that I need to use

```
update-alternatives --config
```

to modify the link. After the change, I can't see the gradle path with

```
which gradle
```

What I shall do to resolve the problem with the following information?

```
abc@linux-mint ~ $ find -L /usr/bin -mindepth 15
find: ‘/usr/bin/gradle’: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: File system loop detected; ‘/usr/bin/X11’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/usr/bin’.
```

And

```
oem@oem-270s ~ $ ls -l /usr/lib/gradle/6.1/bin
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Jan 30 15:05 gradle -> /etc/alternatives/gradle
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2932 Jan 31  1980 gradle.bat
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/gradle/6.1/bin`? It is likely that you have created a loop.

Comment: @icarus You likely is correct. I might mistype a command to get a cycle link. I add the output to my post.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/981/

Comment: So you have /usr/lib/gradle/6.1/bin/gradle which is a link to /etc/alternatives/gradle which is a link to /usr/bin/gradle which is probably a link to /etc/alternatives/gradle which is a link to /usr/bin/gradle which is probably a link to ... I think you got the two filenames to the `ln` command the wrong way around. I suggest reinstalling the latest gradle and then `ln -s /usr/lib/gradle/6.1/bin/gradle /etc/alternatives/gradle`

Comment: I have reinstalled the latest version of Gradle and the situation hasn't changed. I believe that I shouldn't use ln, which is the cause in the first place, but update-alternatives. I, however, don't know how to reconstruct the links.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing all versions of Gradle installments and reinstalled the 6.1 version.